# What is wrong with my RSS Code?

Tags: php, rss

I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at my RSS code because it is outputting a blank page. However, when I run `var_dump()` I am receiving output. Can you please let me know what is going?

```
 if($_GET['uid'] == ''){
    $usrid = $udata['user_name'];
}else{
    $usrid = $_GET['uid'];
}
    $udata = $userObj->fetchUser(array("user_name"=>$usrid));

$rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
$rssfeed .= '<channel>';
$rssfeed .= '<title>Brags By '.$udata['full_name'].'</title>';
$rssfeed .= '<link>'.BASE_URL.'</link>';
$rssfeed .= '<description>'.SITE_TITLE2.'Be amazing. Get noticed.</description>';
$rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
$rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) '.date("Y").' ' . SITE_TITLE2 . '</copyright>'; 

$dbSel = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT *,UP.id as bragid FROM ".USERS_BRAG." as UP,".USERS." as U  where                   U.id = UP.user_id AND UP.status = :stat AND U.id= :uID ORDER BY UP.id DESC");    
$dbSel->execute(array(':stat'=>'1',':uID'=>$udata['id']));
$result=$dbSel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//
while($row = $result) {

    //echo var_dump($row);die;

    $img="<img src='".BASE_URL."public/bragimages/thumb/".$row['brag']."'>";
    $link=BASE_URL."bragdetails/".$row['bragid'];

    $rssfeed .= "<item>";
    $rssfeed .= "<title>".$row['brag_desc']."></title>";
    $rssfeed .= "<description>".$img."></description>";
    $rssfeed .= "<link>".$link."></link>";
    $rssfeed .= "<pubDate>".date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($row['added_date']))."></pubDate>";
    $rssfeed .= "</item>";
}

$rssfeed .= '</channel>';
$rssfeed .= '</rss>';

echo $rssfeed;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `while($row = $result)` is an infinite loop.

Comment: phpcodechecker.com shows `PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in your code on line 8`

Comment: I found this, perhaps it helps: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php#46708

Comment: @SSHThis That's spurious, because the OP forgot the opening `<?php` tag in the code sample, which means line 8's `<?` gets seen as the start of the PHP code.

Comment: Yep, surprisingly, it appears you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use foreach instead

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.